# subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, clamav

Trying to get `clamav` and `clamav-daemon` uninstalled but seems `apt` and `dpkg` are stuck and nothing can complete without this error:

`dpkg --remove` output:

```
(Reading database ... 385080 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing clamav-daemon (0.99.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Failed to stop clamav-daemon.socket: Unit clamav-daemon.socket not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package clamav-daemon (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read clamav-daemon.service
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to read clamav-daemon.socket
Errors were encountered while processing:
 clamav-daemon
```

And any sort of `apt` command adds this to the end:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clamav-daemon : Depends: clamav-base (= 0.99.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) but 0.99.3+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed
                 Recommends: clamdscan but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I've tried the `apt -f install`, tried `dpkg --configure -a`, tried installing and then removing, tried making fake files called `clamav-daemon.service/socket` to hope the script will accept it and continue. Nothing has helped and I'm out of ideas.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-removal script can be found in the following path.

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/clamav-daemon.prerm
```

You should be able to edit this script to remove the part that is failing. Alternatively you can remove the script completely but that may skip other cleanup steps.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the only things in that script were the 2 files it couldn't remove because they didn't exist. Thanks :)